# Google API Console showing "An unexpected error has occurred." after trying to set the "Open URL" to localhost

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-console

I was trying to debug my application using the Drive integration feature by setting the Open URL to `http://localhost/open` which is apparently not permitted.

After a message popped up mentioning that it's not permitted I canceled my changes and exited the page.

After that whenever I access the Google API console and try to select Drive SDK I get a message saying "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it.".

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to contact Google to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top-level domains such as `localhost` are not allowed within the "Open with" context. Use a test domain for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The problem which I have is that setting `localhost` as the "Open with" url (which I shouldn't have done anyway) seems to have made it impossible to access the Drive SDK page in the Google API console, which leaves me completely stuck.

Comment: @jetkiwi, there is a known problem. We're investigating and will provide a hotfix.

Comment: Thank you for you help.
I guess I'll have to work on a different section for the mean time.

Comment: @jetkiwi, API console's Drive SDK section is working again. Please give another try.